# Logstash : Optional match not working as expected

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

lets say i have two kinds of messages coming in

```
1/1/12 dasdahdgh
1/1/12 asd.ert.Tghagsdh
```

now i want something like this

```
%{DATE_US:time}%{SPACE}(%{WORD:stat}|(?<java_method>[a-zA-Z\.]+))
```

if i see a single word after the date, i want to call it stat. If i see the name of a java method, then i want to call it java_method

However, the result i get is

```
{"time":1/1/12, "stat":"dasdahdgh", "java_method":""}
{"time":1/1/12, "stat":"asd", "java_method":".ert.Tghagsdh"}
```

how can i configure my grok so that **only one** of either `stat` or `java_method` is created?

Comment: Also to help you: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a regex which has to have a dot in it, so it will capture `asd.ert.Tghagsdh` but not `dasdahdgh`. By placing it before `%{WORD}`, it will capture the java "method" (it look more like a class), but not the stat:

```
%{DATE_US:time}%{SPACE}((?<java_method>(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)|%{WORD:stat})
```

So you'll have the right values in your fields.

Comment: is this suitable if the java method occurs without any package names? for instance sometime this could be just the name of the method without the full package path

Comment: @AbtPst Well, if there is no package path, there won't be any dot in the method name and the string will not be in the `java_method` field, since for the `java_method`, it is required to have a dot.